# how to modelize a foaf file

Tags: csv, foaf

I'm  doing my master  thesis and I'm working  in serval files which most of them have a csv extension .

I have also  a **foaf file** and I have no idea *how to modelize  and read* this kind of file.
What should I do?

Comment: Please, make your question more concrete. What kind of model do you want to build? Is the foaf file a file with foaf ontology itself or foaf data, etc, etc. I presume, you need a library supporting RDF to read the file in the system you are using. You can also convert it to some other format, CSV for instance.

Comment: Is it like: http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card.rdf ? In any case, for this question to be useful, explain the modelize part. RDF has a very nice graph model and belongs to Semantic Web formats. You file is RDF encoded in XML and can be read by any library or tool, which supports RDF.

Comment: in the beginning  of my file ,  I have a  RDF tag:                                                                                       
and  after it's only a foaf tag so I guess that I need  library supporting RDF  . am I wrong?                                                                                    And if I can use CSv , it will   be easier for me , so  could you help me to  do this task ?

Comment: the RDF tag is  :<rdf:RDF  
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" 
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" 
 xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" 
 xmlns:admin="http://webns.net/mvcb/">

Answer (score 1):

It is a little bit problematic to save RDF data (which "FOAF file" actually is) into some table-like file without sacrificing semantics, because RDF is richer format and converting to CSV is in a way "lossy".

Below is a Python script for naive conversion of RDF into CSV, where each RDF triple is mapped into CSV row (install rdflib library before trying this):

```
from rdflib import Graph
import csv

g = Graph()
g.parse('http://www.w3.org/People/Berners-Lee/card.rdf', format='xml')

with open('card.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for triple in g:
        writer.writerow(triple)
```

To make more sense from RDF one should use some query language and write query (for example, in SPARQL) exactly for the data, which is desired from the RDF file.

Another question/answer which might help you: [RDF file to excel-readable format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28944528/rdf-file-to-excel-readable-format) (ttl is another encoding of RDF: RDF/Turtle )

Comment: thank you for you help, i'm going to try your code , i downloaded python 3.4.3 , is it the right version ?  AND  i mean by modelize : cluster my  file in several  columns  and for exemple collum A : contains persons' name , column B contains  their job etc etc

Comment: Take a look at rdflib docs: http://rdflib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ And Python 3 should be ok.

Comment: To break file into columns you will need to master SPARQL query or program a script, which handles RDF triples. As said, RDF can be framed in many ways, depending on your needs. Rdflib supports SPARQL queries and is not that complex, so I guess it is a better way and you will learn something new in the process. (Personally, I'd converted CSV into RDF, as RDF tools are good at merging many data sources and making them queryable)

Comment: I  tried many days , how to integrate rdflib in python . and I didn't find any solution . I dowlanded python 2.7 and rdf lib 4.2  luck you told me and I don't know how to unstall this library ( I read that I should use  easy_install or pip)  but I don't know where (I clicked  in setup and it doesn't even work) so how can do all of this ?

Comment: I guess, how to install rdflib for Python is a different question. And the answer depends on the operating system being used. The "pip install rdflib" command in the command line should be fine if you have Python and pip installed on your system. It is not enough to click setup.py file, "python setup.py install" is one possible command.

Comment: My operting system is windows 8.1.I use python 2.7 and I thing that pip is already exist  in (C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages).  if everything is already exist where should I install the rdf lib ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know how to do it on your system, but I guess all Python libraries (with some exceptions) can be installed in the same way.